# Mod_rewrite url not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2.4

I have a url

```
**12.2.2.2:8073/abc=200&&Yr=18&Hr=12&Mi=45&Sec=32**
```

what i want is

```
**10.1.250.153:6180/testapp/rest/?abc=200&&Yr=18&Hr=12&Mi=45&Sec=32**
```

so for this

```
 RewriteEngine On

    LogLevel debug rewrite:trace6

    ForensicLog "C:\Apache24\logs\forensic.log"

    RewriteRule "^/(.+)$" "http://10.1.250.153:6180/testapp/rest/?$1"  [NC,L,P]
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://10.1.250.153:6180/testapp/rest"
```

but its not working and in ForensicLog  the url is

+4348:5af043cc:0|GET /abc=200&&Yr=18&Hr=12&Mi=45&Sec=32 HTTP/1.1|Host:12.2.2.2:2222%3a8073|Connection:keep-alive|Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1|User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36|Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8|Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate|Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
-4348:5af043cc:0

Any idea what i might be doing wrong here?

Comment: If the context is .htaccess, then what the RewriteRule checks against _never_ starts with a leading slash, because that has already been stripped off at that point.

Comment: Does it work if you add the `NE` and/or `DPI` flags to your rule?

Comment: @Walf no it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the raw request:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\S+\s+/(\S*)
RewriteRule "^" "http://10.1.250.153:6180/testapp/rest/?%1" [P]
```